# Best / Correct way to store SQLite datasource connection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a very small SQLite application and want to know the best way/place to store the database connection string.  I'm quite new to C#/WPF (hence the question).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an app.config file. These will generate a settings class for you to use.

If you add a `Settings` object from the new item dialog, this will all work great.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to use app.config.

Please Microsoft Article: [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)